# Picostation Not Accepting AREDN Firmware

Tags: microwave, mesh-network

Help! I got a PicoStation off of Ebay. When trying to upload the Amateur Radio Emergency Data Network firmware to it, I get `Bad firmware update image.` How do I get AREDN running on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, you have a Picostation 2. AREDN only supports the Picostation **M2**. I suggest returning it.